# Preventing URLSession redirect in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, redirect

I need to fetch a redirecting URL but **prevent redirection** in Swift. From other posts and Apple docs I understand I must implement the delegate method `URLSession(session:, task:, willPerformHTTPRedirection response:, request:, completionHandler:)` and return `nil` via the completion closure. But I can't find examples in swift, nor figure out the right way to do it. The code below reproduces my issue in playground: the delegate does not seem to get executed.

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)

class MySession: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate {

    // trying to follow instructions at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate/URLSession:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:
    // to prevent redirection -- DOES NOT SEEM TO GET CALLED
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {
        println("in URLSession delegate") // NEVER PRINTS
        completionHandler(nil) // NO EFFECT
    }

    // fetch data from URL with NSURLSession
    class func getDataFromServerWithSuccess(myURL: String, success: (response: String!) -> Void) {
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: myURL)!) { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            // OMITTING ERROR CHECKING FOR BREVITY
            success(response: NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) as String)
        }
        loadDataTask.resume()
    }

    // extract data from redirect
    class func getRedirectionInfo(url: String) {
        getDataFromServerWithSuccess(url) {(data) -> Void in
            if let html = data {
                if html.rangeOfString("<html><head><title>Object moved</title>", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil {
                    println("success: redirection was prevented") // SHOULD PRINT THIS
                } else {
                    println("failure: redirection went through") // INSTEAD PRINTS THIS
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

MySession.getRedirectionInfo("http://bit.ly/filmenczer") // ex. redirecting link
```

Please be gentle, I am a newbie. **Thank you in advance for any assistance!**

**UPDATE:** With many thanks to @nate I got it to work. The key insight is that in order for the delegate to be called, one must *pass the delegate class* to the `NSURLSession()` initializer, rather than using `NSURLSession.sharedSession()`. Passing `nil` as the delegate yields the customary behavior (with redirection). Here is working version of the code:

```
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)

class MySession: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate {

    // to prevent redirection
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(nil)
    }

    // fetch data from URL with NSURLSession
    class func getDataFromServerWithSuccess(myURL: String, noRedirect: Bool, success: (response: String!) -> Void) {
        var myDelegate: MySession? = nil
        if noRedirect {
            myDelegate = MySession()
        }
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: myDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)
        let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: myURL)!) { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            // OMITTING ERROR CHECKING FOR BREVITY
            success(response: NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) as String)
        }
        loadDataTask.resume()
    }

    // extract data from redirect
    class func getRedirectionInfo(url: String) {
        getDataFromServerWithSuccess(url, noRedirect: true) {(data) -> Void in
            if let html = data {
                if html.rangeOfString("<html>\n<head><title>Bitly</title>", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil {
                    println("success: redirection was prevented")
                } else {
                    println("failure: redirection went through")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

MySession.getRedirectionInfo("http://bit.ly/filmenczer")
```

Comment: I think you should check your url, rather than html. `if(url=="redirected url")`.

Comment: Thank you @iphonic but I need to access the body of the response that has the redirect (_Location_) header. In any case the example code is just for illustration purposes to check if redirection is happening or not.

Comment: Yes, that you can do the way you are doing, just check url, instead of html, as url is the correct way to handle redirection than content.

Comment: I do not understand @iphonic, by the time I am checking the content, the redirection has already occurred. I want to **prevent it, not detect it.** Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two things standing in your way with your current implementation.

1. You never set the delegate property on the `NSURLSession` instance that you're using to make the request. Without the delegate property set, your delegate methods won't ever be called. Instead of getting `NSURLSession.sharedSession()`, look at the `NSURLSession(configuration:delegate:delegateQueue:)` initializer. The first and last parameters can be `NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()` and `nil`, respectively, see below for more about the delegate.

   > Note that when you use the variant of `session.dataTaskWithURL` that has a completion handler, delegate methods that handle response and data delivery will be ignored, but authentication and redirection handlers are still used.
2. You'll have to refactor somewhat to use `MySession` as a delegate, since you're using class methods to make the request. You need an instance to use as the session's delegate.

I took a short and incomplete route to having the delegate pick up on the redirect with this alternate code—you'll need to refactor as in #3 to make sure you can still call your callback:

```
class func getDataFromServerWithSuccess(myURL: String, success: (response: String!) -> Void) {
    let delegate = MySession()
    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: myURL)!) {
        // ...
    } 
    task.resume()
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I am studying your kind and very helpful explanations @nate , will be back to confirm once I get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Okay @nate, I got it to work with your help. Your #1 was the key point: rather than using `NSURLSession.sharedSession()`, one needs to pass the delegate to the session initializer.  It turns out #2 is not correct, however; it is okay to use the completion handler in `session.dataTaskWithURL` and the delagate does not get ignored. So the minimal refactoring needed per #3 is to pass a flag to `getDataFromServerWithSuccess()` to indicate whether redirection must be avoided. To prevent redirection, one then passes the delegate to the session initializer. Otherwise pass `nil` as delegate.

Comment: I will update my question with the working code. @nate, I will mark your answer as correct if you kindly revise it to remove or qualify your point #2. **Thank you so much!!!**

Comment: Glad to help! Didn't realize the redirect handler on the delegate was still called—I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I also found the solution helpful, but I am using Swift 4.2 in my current project.

So, here is an adapted shorter version of the solution above, that also works with **Swift 4.2** and **Xcode 10**.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class MySession: NSObject, URLSessionTaskDelegate {

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}

func getDataFromServerWithSuccess(myURL: String, noRedirect: Bool) {
    let myDelegate: MySession? = noRedirect ? MySession() : nil

    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: myDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)
    let loadDataTask = session.dataTask(with: URL(string:myURL)!) { (data, response, error) in

        // OMITTING ERROR CHECKING FOR BREVITY
        if let data = data {
            if let dataString = String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(dataString)
                if dataString.contains("Bitly") == true {
                    print("success: redirection was prevented")
                } else {
                    print("failure: redirection went through")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    loadDataTask.resume()
}

getDataFromServerWithSuccess(myURL: "http://bitly.com/filmenczer", noRedirect: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Minor adjustments to the solutions proposed above. This works with Swift 2 in XCode 7.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(true)

class MySession: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate {

    // to prevent redirection
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: NSHTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: NSURLRequest, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest!) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(nil)
    }

    // fetch data from URL with NSURLSession
    class func getDataFromServerWithSuccess(myURL: String, noRedirect: Bool, success: (response: String!) -> Void) {
    var myDelegate: MySession? = nil
    if noRedirect {
        myDelegate = MySession()
    }
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: myDelegate, delegateQueue: nil)
    let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: myURL)!) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        // OMITTING ERROR CHECKING FOR BREVITY
        success(response: NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) as! String)
    }
    loadDataTask.resume()
    }

    // extract data from redirect
    class func getRedirectionInfo(url: String) {
    getDataFromServerWithSuccess(url, noRedirect: true) {(data) -> Void in
        if let html = data {
            if html.rangeOfString("<html>\n<head><title>Bitly</title>", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil {
                print("success: redirection was prevented")
            } else {
                print("failure: redirection went through")
            }
        }
    }
    }
}

MySession.getRedirectionInfo("http://bit.ly/filmenczer")
```