# Swift / iOS: issue HTTP GET request without following redirects

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

I want my Swift iOS application to fetch the URL it receives via the `NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb` request.

My email service-provider "wraps" the links (like most of them do), returning a "302 redirect" message. I want to do the initial GET, to get "302 Found" and "Location" header, but I don't need iOS to *follow* the redirect for me.

I've added the following code:

```
// Follow the link to trigger click tracking
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
}
task.resume()
```

This works, but I don't need to follow the redirect and fetch all of the data (as it can be quite a large web page).

Does iOS provide a way of getting the initial HTTP(S) response without following the redirect? (A bit like omitting the `--location` flag on CURL).

Comment: PS:  I'm a Swift newbie.
I've tried to use code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070420/preventing-urlsession-redirect-in-swift but this appears to be from an older version of Swift, the namespaces have changed.

Comment: Are you interesting in a `HEAD` request instead, might be better since you don't want the data. But https://stackoverflow.com/a/54639090/1801544 answer of the linked question seems to be working, no?

Comment: The endpoint I'm using responds with `405` to both `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` requests, so I really need a `GET` without following the redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement your custom session with `URLSessionTaskDelegate` extension and then you can interrupt redirection inside `willPerformHTTPRedirection` method:

```
class Redirect : NSObject {
    var session: URLSession?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }
    
    func makeRequest() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://gmail.com")!
        let task = session?.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
        }
        task?.resume()
    }
}

extension Redirect: URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
        // Stops the redirection, and returns (internally) the response body.
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}

let r = Redirect()
r.makeRequest()
```

Outputs:

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/gmail/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: That's working for me, thank you. Is there a way to return the location header back to the calling code? I've changed makeRequest to include
if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        let location = response.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Location")

but can't figure out how to return the value back from the makeRequest call

Comment: @steve you can return it with a callback closure that is passed as arg with `makeRequest` and call inside data task callback. e.g. `let callback: (String) -> Void = { location in ...}`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [iUrii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/979986/iurii) and [kleids](https://github.com/kleids) I got this working, a few points to note:

- A callback is needed to get data out of the async task
- Updating UILabels can only happen from the main queue (!!) so the                 DispatchQueue.main.async {} is needed

```swift
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  testlinks
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
    
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }
    
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }
    
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }
    
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }
    
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        // First attempt at handling a universal link
        print("Continue User Activity called: ")
        if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
           let url = userActivity.webpageURL {
            //handle URL
            let r = Redirect()
            r.makeRequest(url: url, callback: { (location) in
                
                guard let locationURL = location else {return}
                
                print("locationURL", locationURL)
                
                // Show this on our simple example app
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let vc = self.window?.rootViewController as? ViewController {
                        vc.result.text = url.absoluteString
                        vc.originalURL.text = locationURL.absoluteString
                    }
                    
                }
            })
        }
        return true
    }
}

// More efficient click-tracking with HTTP GET to obtain the "302" response, but not follow the redirect through to the Location.
// The callback is used to return the Location header back from the async task = thanks @kleids
class Redirect : NSObject {
    var session: URLSession?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }
    
    func makeRequest(url: URL, callback: @escaping (URL?) -> ()) {
        let task = self.session?.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            guard response != nil else {
                return
            }
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                if let l = response.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Location") {
                    callback(URL(string: l))
                }
            }
        }
        task?.resume()
    }
}

extension Redirect: URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
        // Stops the redirection, and returns (internally) the response body.
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
}
```